# How can I convert cents to units in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, currency

For example I have 1000 cents which would be 10 dollars, how can I do it?
this is my code, I have data taken from an API

```
    <b-button variant="outline-primary mb-2">
{{contract.reward_cents}} {{contract.reward_currency}}
</b-button>
```

Comment: `{{ Number(contract.reward_cents) / 100 }}`

Comment: [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) is probably worth a look.

Comment: Thanks it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure if i understand you correctly. you just want `contract.reward_cents` to be converted to dollars?

you can do it like this:

```
{{ Number(contract.reward_cents)/100 }}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works